# Get first char from std::string

Tags: c++, string, char

I need to get the first character of an `std::string` with a minimum amount of code.

It would be great if it would be possible to get the first char in one line of code, from an STL `std::map<std::string, std::string> map_of_strings`. Is the following code correct:

```
map_of_strings["type"][0]
```

**EDIT**
Currently, I am trying to use this piece of code. Is this code correct?

```
if ( !map_of_strings["type"].empty() )
    ptr->set_type_nomutex( map_of_strings["type"][0] );
```

The prototype of the `set_type` function is:

```
void set_type_nomutex(const char type);
```

Comment: "Does not work" is not a problem description.

Comment: What do you mean "does not work correctly"?  What happened?  What did you expect to happen?

Comment: Are you sure that prototype is correct? If you're using `type` as the key to the map you should have gotten a compile error.

Comment: In what way doesn't `map_of_strings["type"][0]` work? What is the exact type of `map_of_strings`? What is the error message?

Comment: map_of_strings is probably something like, std::map<std::string,std::string>

Comment: You need to show more relevant code. For example the declaration of `map_of_strings` and the implementation of `set_type_nomutex`. This code certainly won't compile as shown.

Comment: First message edited. Added some code like I trying to use its. of course, its std::map<std::string,std::string>. The main question is this like of code correct?

Comment: sorry, at the first message parsing function of stackoverflow does not show full prototype of the map near <>, before I did not edited it and add some additional spaces after < and before >

Comment: @abrahab: You can surround code with backticks (```) to make it appear as written. Unless the code itself is a backtick, apparently.

Comment: a pity that I can not mark both answers from mike-seymour and @bames53 as accepted. thanks. bames53 suggested good and _short_ peace of code with range check, that can be used to give some default value to the function if type is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not exactly clear from your question what your problem is, but the thing likely to go wrong with `map_settings["type"][0]` is that the returned string may be empty, resulting in undefined behavior when you do `[0]`. You have to decide what you want to do if there is no first character. Here's a possibility that works in a single line.

```
ptr->set_type_nomutex( map_settings["type"].empty() ? '\0' : map_settings["type"][0]);
```

It gets the first character or a default character.

Answer (score 6):

That should work if you've put a non-empty string into `map_of_strings["type"]`. Otherwise, you'll get an empty string back, and accessing its contents will probably cause a crash.

If you can't be sure whether the string exists, you can test:

```
std::string const & type = map["type"];
if (!type.empty()) {
    // do something with type[0]
}
```

Or, if you want to avoid adding an empty string to the map:

```
std::map<std::string,std::string>::const_iterator found = map.find("type");
if (found != map.end()) {
    std::string const & type = found->second;
    if (!type.empty()) {
        // do something with type[0]
    }
}
```

Or you could use `at` to do a range check and throw an exception if the string is empty:

```
char type = map["type"].at(0);
```

Or in C++11, the map also has a similar `at` which you can use to avoid inserting an empty string:

```
char type = map.at("type").at(0);
```

Answer (score 4):

The c_str() method will return a pointer to the internal data. If the string is empty, then a pointer to a NULL-termination is returned, so a simple one-liner is safe and easy:

```
std::string s = "Hello";
char c = *s.c_str();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string s("type");
char c = s.at(0);
```

Comment: Note `.at(0)` will throw an `out_of_range` exception for an empty string. Otherwise it's the same behavior as `operator[]`